# Flutter - Flutter Local Notification Sound didn't Play on MIUI 11.0.1?

Tags: android, flutter

I've used package flutter_local_notifications 2.0.0+1.

Is there a way to force allow sound without allow manual on setting notif in app on MIUI 11.0.1 especially for e.g. Xiaomi, Huawei device ?

Comment: did you find any fix for this?

Comment: is about device manufactures, you can read here https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/852#issuecomment-827995444 @MrRandom